# Span badge is overlayed during hover on image

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use the following code to display the sale badge on my shop and category pages

```
function woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail() {
    $w_g_p_t = woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail();
    global $product;
    if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        
        // On sale
        $is_on_sale = $product->is_on_sale();
        
        // True
        if ( $is_on_sale ) {
            $rrp_price        = (int) $product->get_regular_price();
            $sale_price       = (int) $product->get_price();
            
            // Greater than
            if ( $rrp_price > $sale_price ) {
                $discount_amount  = $rrp_price - $sale_price;
                $discount_percent = '-' . round( ( $discount_amount / $rrp_price ) * 100, 0 ) . '%';
                $w_g_p_t          = '<span class="wpd-sale-thumbnail"><span class="wpd-sale-badge">' . $discount_percent . '</span>' . $w_g_p_t . '</span>';
            }
        }
    }
    
    echo $w_g_p_t;
    
}
This is the css
```

and this outputs it correctly.
However on hover the badge gets overlayed
by the second image.
I've tried changing it with wp_get_attachment_image and get_gallery_image_ids but can't seem to get it to work.
What should i look into?
link to website myonlinemall.mk
This is the css

```
span.wpd-sale-badge {
        background: #0f0f0f;
        color: white !important;
        height: 65px;
        display: block;
        width: 65px;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 100px;
        font-size: 1.0625em; !important;
        line-height:  65px!important;
        top:74%;
        left:74%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 99;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .wpd-sale-thumbnail {
        position: sticky;
        display: block;!important
    }
```

This is the html

```
class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">

<span class="wpd-sale-thumbnail">
<span class="wpd-sale-badge">-61%</span><img width="500" height="500" 
src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns=&#039;http://www.w3.org/2000/svg&#039;%20viewBox=&#039;0%200%20370%20247&#039;%3E%3C/svg%3E"
```

Comment: This is a CSS issue. Post your HTML and CSS. The PHP doesn't tell us anything regarding this issue.

Comment: I have updated the css, my bad

Comment: We need the HTML as well.

Comment: I have updated my html as well, thank you